# Why do i need to explicitly import modules when they're already imported?

Tags: python, sys

Whenever I run the command on Ubuntu Linux:

```
python3 -v
```

I get a verbose output which tells me:

```
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import sys # builtin
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
```

And much much more.

However, I see that import sys was executed, yet I still need to manually import sys to use it. Why is this happening?

Comment: `import` is *per-namespace*. Importing something into one module's namespace stores it in the cache, but doesn't make it available to other modules without explicit request -- if this weren't true, you'd never know which names were and weren't in your namespace, because they could have been imported by random other code on the system!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short (and inaccurate) version: `import foo` does two separate things:

- it looks for and loads from disc the module named "foo", *if* *necessary*
- it [binds](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) the module to the name `foo` in the current namespace

You have to "manually import" `sys` for the same reason that this doesn't work:

```
>>> def r():
...     import random
...     print(random.randint(0, 100))
... 
>>> r()
26
>>> random.randint(10, 20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

A way to demonstrate that import is nothing magic:

```
$ cat foo.py 
print('foo has been imported')

def fn():
    print('fn has been called')
$ python
>>> import importlib
>>> bar = importlib.__import__('foo')
foo has been imported
>>> bar.fn()
fn has been called
```

The module name works like any other name in Python:

`importlib.__import__()` creates a value (a module, in this case) and the `=` assigns it to the name.

With a conventional import, `import foo` creates a value (the same module) and assigns it to the given name (which just happens to be the same as the module name).

You can verify that a module is only loaded once like this:

```
$ python
>>> import foo
foo has been imported
>>> import foo
>>>
```

and you can demonstrate that a module is just another value:

```
>>> import foo
foo has been imported
>>> foo.fn()
fn has been called
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar.fn()
fn has been called
```

Comment: `importlib.__import__` is an oxymoron.  Use `importlib.import_module`.

Comment: @wim: i don't think that word means what you think it means… anyway, yes, `__import__()` is discouraged in favour of `import_module()`, but the former is what is invoked by the `import` statement.

Comment: Nope, that's incorrect.  The import statement uses `builtins.__import__`.  You can prove it to yourself with `import importlib; del importlib.__import__` and then import any module - it will still work.  Delete the `builtins.__import__` and it will stop working.  I know what oxymoron means, and the whole point of using `importlib` is to provide a public API so that you are **not** using `__import__`.

Comment: i give up, you win